# jquery - finding elements in a table and changing other elements based on findings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to adapt other examples with similar questions here on stackoverflow... but am stumped right now.

Here's what my html table looks like after it's been rendered:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="status">
  <thead>
    <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
           <th>REP</th>
           <th>Package</th>
           <th> CV</th>
           <th>Latest CV</th>
           <th>Custom </th>
           <th>Status</th>    
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>     
    <tr>
        <td>asfasdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="package">tmm</td>
        <td>tmm-4.2.7-r1</td>
        <td>4.2.7-r1</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="status_button"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success"></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="package">a-cis</td>
        <td>a-cis-0.1.0-r0</td>
        <td>0.1.0-r0</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="status_button"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"></button></td>
    </tr>    
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**What I need:**

After the table has been rendered, I want to find all rows that have a danger button ("btn-danger") and change the color of the text in the "Package" cell / td to red.

Based on similar questions here on stackoverflow, here's what I have so far:

```
122 <script>
123 $( document ).ready(function() {
124         $('.status_button').each(function(i, n) {
125                 console.log($(n.innerHTML));
126                 //somehow id the sibling <td> that has class
127                 //package and change the font color
128                 //to red
129         });
130 });
131 
132 </script>
```

The console.log matches a property in the object and displays... but my "if" statement fails. 
I was trying to copy the contents of my console.log to paste in here but haven't been successful yet.

Any tips on how i can test the value of the button class and then alter the text color in the Package field would be appreciated

Thanks.

EDIT 1

So I changed the each function to look for the btn-danger class ... and that seems to work better because it filters more results. 
But I guess I still need help changing the sibling td with the class "package" to display text in red.

```
122 <script>
123 $( document ).ready(function() {
124         $('.btn-danger').each(function(i, n) {
125                 console.log($(n.innerHTML));
126                 if ($(n.innerHTML) == "button.btn.btn-danger") {
127                         alert('red!!');
128                 };
129         });
130 });
131 
132 </script>
```

Comment: I'm gong to try to search for btn-danger class instead of the status_button class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [:has](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector to filter all cells with class status_button having the button you are looking for.

In order to change the color of cell with class package you can use [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.status_button:has("button.btn.btn-danger")').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).siblings('.package').css('color', 'red');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped" id="status">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>REP</th>
        <th>Package</th>
        <th> CV</th>
        <th>Latest CV</th>
        <th>Custom</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>asfasdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="package">tmm</td>
        <td>tmm-4.2.7-r1</td>
        <td>4.2.7-r1</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="status_button">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="package">a-cis</td>
        <td>a-cis-0.1.0-r0</td>
        <td>0.1.0-r0</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="status_button">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: bingo!  That's exactly what I was looking for!  thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use jQuery, instead use the search for `.btn-danger`. It's simpler and does exactly what you want.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.btn-danger').each(function(i, n) {
     var thisRow = n.closest('tr');
     $(thisRow).css("color", "red");
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped" id="status">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>REP</th>
      <th>Package</th>
      <th> CV</th>
      <th>Latest CV</th>
      <th>Custom </th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>asfasdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="package">tmm</td>
      <td>tmm-4.2.7-r1</td>
      <td>4.2.7-r1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="status_button">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="package">a-cis</td>
      <td>a-cis-0.1.0-r0</td>
      <td>0.1.0-r0</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="status_button">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hey there. i guess we were both on the same page.  please see the comment i added and related section in my question called "EDIT 1".  I updated my code to do the same thing you're suggesting here.  But now I just need to know how to change any <td>s in the same row that have a class "package"... to print in red font.

Comment: @Happydevdays I edited it with your update. Hope it helps.